# Graphstream Multithreading - Java

Tags: java

I am relatively new to the threading world in Java and need some help please. I am using a deep recursion algorithm to build a graph, based on the Graphstream (http://graphstream-project.org/) libray. However I encounter a Stackoverflow error. I am sure my algorithm is right (I tested on a small scale).

I read about threading and how this could help. My idea is to generate a new thread for each recursion (might go to millions :( ).. That would also generate a lot of sub graphs.. In the end, I would have to merge all those sub graphs in a single thread. Do you guys think that this would really help getting rid of the stackoverflow problem? Or do you have any other ideas for me!? Thanks!

Comment: post some code and Exception Stack. This error occurs mostly when you run out of heap, mostly in case of going infinite loop

Comment: Threading is not, IMHO, the right answer for StackOverflowErrors caused by recursion. Youd' better replace the recursion by an iteration, using a stack for example.

Comment: Try iteration instead of recursion. Without tail-call optimisation, java won't handle 1m recursive function invocations.

Comment: Thank you guys for the fast answer. I have already tried to increase the stack (-Xss20m). Still the function does not terminate. It just run through more recursions.
So bottom lines, even using threading wouldn't help me at all?? I was kinda trying to avoid iteration.

Comment: @Reddy, StackOverflowError occurs when you run out of **stack**, not heap. If you run out of heap and try to allocate something on the heap, you'll likely get an OutOfMemoryError.

Comment: @BrunoReis, Sorry, I might be thinking something else while typing that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your idea is, in general, called [MapReduce](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MapReduce). Googling that should help you find a sample implementation.

Since your problem is a stack overflow error, remember, that you can rewrite each recursion to a looped algorithm which will not cause stack overflow errors.

Creating a lot of threads is usually a bad idea. Just use a `ThreadPool` or an `Executor` service.

Comment: thanks mate.. I also read a lot about iterative solutions. But that would be my last shot. The recursive solution is, of course, sexier.

I took a look at the different solutions you guys suggested me. However, I am struggling applying this to the Graph context.

Basically, for each new node computed, the recursive function is called. The different tutorials I read suggest to use a threshold or a kind of limitation for when to divide the task. But for building a graph, I kinda not have a limitation at all... Do you guys get me?

Comment: @pro if you have problems with rewriting the algorithm create a new dedicated question for it, show us what you have tried so far, and we will (probably:) help you. This question is about a different topic and it should stay this way.

Comment: You right.. Sorry.. I will be opening a new topic for that.. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Millions of threads is not an elegant way. Instead of threads, launch Runnables on an java.concurrent.Executor. This way you'll also get rid of Stackoverflow, and make the algorithm run in parallel on all available processors.

Comment: Thanks Alexei. I hear you! The idea would have been to create a new thread for every 100 or 200 recursions or so.. I will take a look at your suggestion. I will get back to you asap. Thanks

Comment: @pro the idea is to not create threads at all, create jobs which are submitted to the Executor, which has a certain amount of threads which he reuses. Grouping several (hundreds? thousands?) nodes per job is a good idea, because the synchronization overhead will be smaller.

Comment: Awesome.. I got that one done. This is pretty straightforward using Java 1.7. I was used to parallelism using C++

**@Alexei** As I am dealing with a load of data, I preferred using the Fork/Join Framework from Java 1.7. I found a very good article [here](http://www.vogella.com/articles/JavaConcurrency/article.html) which explains each paradigm quite well...